# "view argument is nil" when inserting/removing item in UICollectionView with subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've added a `UICollectionView` to a `UIViewController` using a Storyboard. This `UICollectionView` uses a custom layout: A subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

When I'm now trying to insert or remove an item to/from my `UICollectionView` …

```
// allData is an array and the data source of collectionView
[self.allData addObjectsFromArray:dataToAdd];

// collectionViewIndexPaths is an array with one or more UIIndexPath objects
[self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:collectionViewIndexPaths];
```

… the app crashes and throws this exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'view argument is nil'

I don't know which view argument is meant here.

When I'm not using my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass but the Flow Default Layout, everything works fine – the item is inserted into the collection view.

Therefore the source of this error should be obvious: The `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass!

```
@interface MyFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end

@implementation MyFlowLayout

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {

        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(95, 160);
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 8, 10, 0);
        self.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(50, 2);
        self.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(50, 2);
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Yes, that's the whole subclass. Originally I put a lot of stuff here, but I get the error in both cases: With this minimum version of the subclass and with the more complex version.

As I mentioned above, the only case I don't get this error is when using the default flow layout (now subclass).

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you take a look at the stack trace to get an idea what was going on when the exception occurred?

Comment: Unfortunately the stack trace isn't very informative (as it's very short): It just shows me that the crash happens at `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`